# CPU being used up by some background process

Tags: laptop, cpu, performance, cpu-usage, task-manager

I have a fairly new windows 10 laptop that I've been using, and today it was running very slowly. I opened up my task manager and found these background processes that are collectively taking up almost 100% of my cpu usage, but I'm not sure what they are. I ended those tasks for now but I would like to know what they are in case they ever come up again.

One of them is called ".▯▯▯000600000007bef01a39bf74345ff998" and when I click on "open file location", it leads me to the recycle bin which is empty.

Any ideas on what they might be used for?

[cpu task manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/homFJ.png)

Comment: Is it running updates?  Could be if new. Let it run, let it update, let it finish, restart and test. Then run a full Virus Scan with Windows Defender. A decently set up Windows 10 machine should use less than 5% CPU more than 95% of the time.

Comment: it's about 3 months old, and I don't think it's running updates. I will try the restart and full virus scan that you mentioned

Comment: If you are suspicious of the task I would perform a Reset on your installation.  Since you cannot identify the process I would choose NOT to keep your personal files.  Be sure you backup your personal files.

Comment: There is less than a 0% chance those processes have anything to do with Windows Update

Comment: Yup - looks like you got scammed by the botnet already - maybe download fewer hooky games/pron. Nuke & pave, don't take anything across to the new install, let it all burn. See [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep your existing install as is, because the machine is new, try reviewing CPU usage.

For reviewing Windows CPU and Disk Usage (as a minimum) run Windows 10 Admin Tools, Resource Monitor.

Let it run for 15 to 20 minutes and see what is using CPU and Disk (this usage constitutes most slow downs).

[image]